# replace abcde[Backspace][Backspace] -> abc

Tags: regex

How would I construct regex so I can perform replacements like these:

- `abcdef[Backspace][Backspace][Backspace]` -> `abc`
- `[Backspace][Backspace]` -> (empty string)

Currently, I'm trying to replace backspaces one-by-one in a loop. Is there another way?

Comment: What language -slash- regex-flavor?

Comment: Also, when you say `[Backspace]`, do you mean the ASCII backspace character (`\b` / `\008` / U+0008), or do you mean the eleven-character sequence `[` + `B` + ... + `e` + `]`? Because your current regex, `[^\\[Backspace\\]]\\[Backspace\\]`, doesn't seem like it would work for either one!

Comment: @ruakh doubling those backslashes assumes certain languages (e.g. Java). in many others you don't need to do that.

Comment: ruakh, I mean 11-character sequence. Edited.

Comment: that is by accident `[^\\[Backspace\\]]` means, any character that is not a square bracket or `B`, `a`, `c`, `k`, `s`, `p`, `e`. (Try `abc[Backspace][Backspace][Backspace]` for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness, here is a solution using a negative lookbehind (the one that you probably intended to use yourself):

```
(^|.(?<!\[Backspace]))\[Backspace]
```

And replace with an empty string. Do this in a loop. If you are using Java or there are some other circumstances that require escaping of backslashes, double the two backslashes.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that comes to mind is replacing `.\[Backspace\]` with empty string in a loop as long as there is a match. Then replace `\[Backspace\]` with empty string globally.

Edit: as raised in comments, the answer does not work too well when we have too many backspaces.

As a solution, we could replace all `^\[Backspace\]` with empty string before each iteration of  `.\[Backspace\]` replacement.

Assuming Perl rules for grouping, `s/^(?:\[Backspace\])*//` will do the trick.

Comment: you should probably turn that `.` into a `[^]]` (otherwise the second input example would case problems). On the other hand, the proper solution would probably be a negative lookbehind, to allow for deleting unrelated `]`, too.

Comment: That won't work too well for `a]b[Backspace][Backspace]`. A better solution is needed - I'll edit the answer

Comment: Thank you! However, I could not believe that there are no better way. Currenltly I use analogous method.

Comment: @nichiporets, it is just that your current approach does not really work, because you use negated character class instead of a negative lookbehind

Comment: You can combine those two replacements -- start-of-string and not -- by writing (in Perl notation) `s/(^|.)\[Backspace\]//s`. (In Perl, the entire loop would be `1 while s/(^|.)\[Backspace\]//s;`. Alas, most other languages don't allow such terseness.)

Comment: @ruakh, this would still be problematic with stuff like `[Backspace][Backspace][Backspace]`. In the first run, it would match twice and result in `[Backspace`.

Comment: @m.buettner: Nope; it would only do that if you added a `g` flag, which no-one has suggested doing!

Comment: @ruakh that depends on the tool/language used. some will do that by default (or someone might try it without giving it too much thought). so I thought it's worth pointing out.

Comment: Yes, you may need to run `^...` regexp until it stops matching at the end.